# How to format PHP into the proper string for JSON in pie chart using highchart

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am a new to Highcharts json and I'm using the pie chart with gradient fill. I have been facing issues for the past few days with extracting json data from php  to populate a pie chart with gradient fill. Already tried SO answers but still i am unable to find proper solution. My chart not shows on browser but json data displays here.

```
 [{"name":{"MOZILA":45.0}},{"name":{"IE":26.8}},{"name":{"CHROME":12.8}},{"name":{"OPERA":6.2}},{"name":{"OTHERS":9.2}}]
```

Here my problem is I can't know know how to convert format php into proper string for json. problem is in json code and json encodeing .

Here my **index.php**:

```
       $(function () {

       // Radialize the colors
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
    });

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ' Rate of a specific project'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    },
                    connectorColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total Marketing',
            data:[]

        }]
    });
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(data){

        //options.series[6].data = json;
            chart.series[0].setData(data);

           chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
   });
```

Here is my **data.php** :

```
$sql="SELECT mozila,ie,chrome,opera,safari,torch FROM webmarketing";
$resultSql = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultSql)) {
    $result[] = array('name' => array('MOZILA' => $rows['mozila']));
   $result[] = array('name' => array('IE' => $rows['ie']));
   $result[] = array('name' => array('CHROME' => $rows['chrome']));
   $result[] = array('name' => array('OPERA' => $rows['opera']));
   $result[] = array('name' => array('OTHERS' => $rows['safari']+$rows['torch']));
   }
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Error in graph 
[image]

So kindly request to you Please tell me How to extract data from php and mysql to json code.

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your question what you WANT the JSON to look likeCan you clarify whether the example string you have at the tope of your post is the format you want your JSON string to have? Also, does your SQL query return more than one row or just a single row?

Comment: @davidethell Thanking you for response. I need to know how to extract PHP and MySql data through json code for Pie chart using Highcharts.From my php file, Json_encode prints something this:[{"name":{"MOZILA":45.0}},{"name":{"IE":26.8}},{"name":{"CHROME":12.8}},{"name":{"OPERA":6.2}},{"name":{"OTHERS":9.2}}]  .But when i set these datas within json function ,My graph not generate with my code .So tell me how can i pass my php data into json function .

Comment: I have edited my answer to change your PHP output to match what Highlight seems to require.

Comment: @davidethell...I have changed all my code but still graph not displays. please tell me where is wrong.

Comment: @davidethell Thanks for your response.I checked my json data is right,i can't understand why my graph not display.I have tried all SO solutions but i am failed .So please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Highlight charts documentation it seems your JSON output needs to change a bit. Assuming your query returns only a single row, I think this is what you want:

```
$result = array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultSql)) {
    $result[] = array('name' => 'MOZILA', 'y' => $rows['mozila']);
    $result[] = array('name' => 'IE', 'y' => $rows['ie']);
    $result[] = array('name' => 'CHROME', 'y' => $rows['chrome']);
    $result[] = array('name' => 'OPERA', 'y' => $rows['opera']);
    $result[] = array('name' => 'OTHERS', 'y' => $rows['safari']+$rows['torch']);
```

}

Then just eliminate all the array_push calls since that happens in the while loop.

If you have more than one row then the above logic will not be what you're looking for since you probably want a GROUP BY to SUM your results.

Your chart javascript is also not correct. You are rendering the chart to a container without saving it to a variable. Later when you try to save it to a chart variable it has no connection to your initial chart. Try this instead:

```
var chart;
$(function () {

   // Radialize the colors
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
    };
});

// Build the chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ' Rate of a specific project'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                },
                connectorColor: 'silver'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Total Marketing',
        data:[]

    }]
});
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(data){

        chart.series[0].setData(data);

    });
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your response.Now my query returns me multiple rows.But how can i call this json result within json function in index.php page .so my graph will be produce. i am calling like this      $.getJSON("data.php", function(json){
             chart.series[0].setData(data);
          var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });  is it right to call json result .

Comment: You are not setting your var chart variable in the proper place and your getJSON function argument needs to be 'data' since that's what you are passing to setData. See my edits above. All this is untested, but it should get you close enough to put you in the proper direction.

Comment: Still graph not displays.Please tell me solution.

Comment: now my graph not shows ,it displays only [object Object]:0.0 .Please give me solution why it occurs.

Comment: Please tell me why my graph shows me [object Object]:0.0 .Not shows graph.i attached my image on above.